# Applescript to check the first letter of user input

Tags: applescript

I'm having a hard time knowing where to start with this.

I'm setting up a pre made email that would fill in the message content text with the location of the file.

What I'm trying to do is find out what the first letter of a codename that is input by a user and the result is assigned to a variable.  If the first letter in the variable is A then it would be in folder A-D, if its E it would be in E-H.

Then in my email I would say something like:

Codename is available:
resources/images/web_images/A-D/Codename.jpg

or

Ecodename is available:
resources/images/web_images/E-H/ecodename.jpg

I can get the user input and assign the variable but its checking the first letter against the possible locations and then assigning the new location to a variable that can be used in the email.

This part of the script is part of a larger script that. An overview of what it does is: It opens a pdf in photoshop, resizes it and names it to a users input code, saves the file to the desktop and builds an email with where the image WILL be located, if it starts with A-B it will be in a specific folder, E-G in a different existing folder. I will manually place the image there but I want to check the input name (codename) so when I build the email I can append the location automatically.

I believe this is an if else but not sure.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely confident I've understood your question fully, but having seen the other answer's approach and your comment against it, I'm hoping that I'm in the ball park.

As you stated that you know how to acquire user input and assign that to a variable, I have not included those aspects as part of my script below.

Instead, I created a dummy property value that stores a made up value of what I imagined a user might input as the codename.

```
property userInput : "GXTrZy"
```

You can delete this line and substitute any occurrences of `userInput` in my script for the name of the variable that you used to store the actual user input.

```
property userInput : "Dinosaur" -- A dummy value to take the place of user input
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
property resourcePath : "resources/images/web_images"
property resourceFolders : ["A-B", "C-F", "G-I", "J-O", "P-S", "T-Z"]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
property alphabet : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(*

    Your code to obtain user input
    and assign it to a variable, etc.

    I have put a dummy placeholder codename
    in the property value 'userInput' at
    the top of this script.

*)

set alpha to the first character of the userInput --> "D"
if alpha is not in the alphabet then return
set x to (alpha's id) mod 32 -- Alpha's ordinal position in the alphabet

set || to words of (resourceFolders as text) as text --> "ABCFGIJOPSTZ"
set the text item delimiters to {"/"} & ||'s items
--> {"/", "A", "B", "C", "F", "G", "I", "J", "O", "P", "S", "T", "Z"}

set |ₓ| to text 1 thru x of the alphabet --> "ABCD"
set |₋| to text items of ("+" & |ₓ|) as text --> "+///D"

set i to 0.49 + (offset of alpha in ||) / 2 as integer --> 0
set j to the (number of words in |₋|) * ((|₋| contains alpha) as integer) --> 2

set n to i + j --> Index of folder item in resourceFolders list = 2

set resourceFolder to item n of resourceFolders --> "C-F"

set filepath to the {resourcePath, resourceFolder, [userInput, ".jpg"]} as text
set msg to ["The codename you input : ", userInput, linefeed, ¬
    "The file for that codename is available at : ", filepath] as text

(*

    The rest of your code will follow
    below.  You can use the message stored
    in the variable 'msg' to append to 
    your email. 

*)
```

The line of specific interest in reference to your question is this one here:

```
set alpha to the first character of the userInput --> "D"
```

It gets the first letter of the codename and stores it in the variable `alpha`.  The lines of code that follow on from that deal with identifying the correct folder that houses the codename's resource file.

The comments after some of the lines of code start with `--` or `-->`, the latter of which I've used to print out the result at each stage of the script's execution based on the sample user input that I supplied.  Therefore, the letter being processed was `"G"`, and the results shown relate to this letter, but will be different with different sample inputs that use a different first letter.

After running this script, the final output was the message string stored in the variable `msg`, which contained the following text:

```
"The codename you input : Dinosaur
The file for that codename is available at : resources/images/web_images/C-F/Dinosaur.jpg"
```

---

**UPDATE:** 2018-09-26 - **An iterative method**

Here's an alternative method of achieving the same goal using a `repeat` loop to iterate through each possible resource folder name and test if the codename's letter falls between the letters of folder name:

```
property userInput : "Dinosaur" -- A dummy value to take the place of user input
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
property resourceFolders : ["A-B", "C-F", "G-I", "J-O", "P-S", "T-Z"]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
set alpha to the first character of the userInput --> "D"

set ASCIIindices to the id of (words in (resourceFolders as text) as text)
set alphaIndex to ((alpha's id) mod 32) + 64 -- Case independent

repeat with i from 2 to the length of ASCIIindices by 2
    if item i of ASCIIindices ≥ the alphaIndex then exit repeat
end repeat

set resourceFolder to item (i / 2) of the resourceFolders --> "C-F"
```

<sup>The code is shorter, and it's actually the more obvious method to use to solve a problem of this nature.  However, I tend to generalise problems before working on a solution, which is where my more mathematically-oriented solution above came from.</sup>

<sup>The theoretical benefits of the first solution is that its speed in execution is only limited by the speed of AppleScript's builtin functions like `offset` and the text manipulation features, i.e. the actually AppleScript code will never slow the process down regardless of how long the alphabet is.</sup>

<sup>Meanwhile, the iterative method is an `O(n)` algorithm that would get slower with a longer alphabet, as its limiting factor in speed is the `repeat` loop that would require infinite time with an infinite alphabet.</sup>

<sup>But, seeing as we don't have an infinite alphabet, this is really a moot point, and so you may elect to use the shorter, more easy-to-follow method. I personally dislike `repeat` loops and avoid them whenever necessary, but that's strictly my peculiar trait in coding.</sup>

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for thank you!  I have a couple more questions about it. 1. What are these characters you are using |ₓ|, is it just a unicode as a variable or does it have some other quality. 2. When I change the resourceFolders to my folders like this: property resourceFolders : ["A-B", "C-F", "G-I", "J-O", "P-S", "T-Z"] the script points to the wrong folder when its between. Ex. if the codename is Dinosaur the result is... web_images/A-B/Dinosaur.jpg. Why is this?  If I may ask, how did you learn AppleScript, this script is a little black box to me. Thanks again

Comment: The variable names with unusual unicode characters are not inherently special - I just didn't know what else to call them.  Let me get back to you on the issue you found with a fix - thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I've fixed the code to deal with the issue you raised.  It was a result of something I overlooked but was fixed by changing the line that now reads `set |₋| to text items of ("+" & |ₓ|) as text`.  It should work universally now.  I've also provided a second, more conventional method of doing the same thing using `repeat` loop.  Both are equally suitable to use for your problem.

Comment: Regarding how I learnt AppleScript, I did the same as I do for any programming language I want to learn: I set out to write a script; I initially don't know how; so I steal someone else's code; I play around with it and discover how changing things changes the outcome; I start formulating my own scripts; they usually don't work at first; but I alter things and take note of the effects, including how the error changes.  Then you get to a point where you know enough to write your own code from scratch, and other people can steal (borrow) from me. _Cont'd..._

Comment: Above all, I'm naturally curious.  I notice the people who repeatedly ask questions on Stack Overflow lack curiosity to solve basic problems themselves, simply by changing a line of code in every possible way one can think of and seeing its effect.  Instead, a year later, they still get defeated because one line doesn't work; they don't experiment, so don't learn by doing.  It's all about experimentation.  It has pitfalls, as I once deleted a ton of system files learning bash and it crippled my machine.  But it's all part of the fun.  _Con'td..._

Comment: I also read documentation on Apple's developer website.  Apple documentation is usually excellent once you get to a point where you know roughly how the syntax of a language works.  Lastly, I'm still learning—as we all are, all of the time—but I do this by helping and teaching others, which happens every time I contribute to Stack Overflow and solve someone else's problem.  I might not know how to do it at first, but I figure it out, and research, learn something new in the process, then submit an answer that teaches someone else how to do it and consolidates my understanding.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you for your generous help and insights into coding. Just getting scripts to work is my current goal with hopes of elegant code someday. Thanks again.